# How to cache UAC credentials in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, uac

Is there any way to allow Windows to remember the username and password entered into the UAC prompt in Windows 10?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I’m wondering if there is any way that make windows remember the username and password when you enter them into the UAC prompt in Windows 10?

What you want is to change the behavior of UAC from `Prompt for credentials` to `Prompt for consent for non-Windows binaries`.

As per the detailed explanation [here](https://www.eightforums.com/threads/uac-change-prompt-behavior-for-administrators-in-windows.41136/), if you import [this](https://www.eightforums.com/attachments/admin_uac_prompt_for_consent_for_non-windows_binaries-reg.37597/) registry key, the behavior of your UAC will revert from asking from credentials to simply asking for you to choose between "Yes" and "No", which is functionally identical to the situation you would be in had you cached your credentials.

[image]

From a security perspective, you will still be in the loop and will still be required in order to approve a non-Windows binary before it executes, you just won't need to enter your password every time.

Answer (score 0):

No. UAC is a security mechanism and as such it is designed not to remember passwords. This prevents inadvertently remembering admin credentials.